# Pulse effect with CSS box-shadow by using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create pulse effect with css box-shadow by using jquery. I tried following code but completely failed. **What i am trying to achieve is a smooth pulse effect with box-shadow**

The code that i tried is
html

```
<div class="one">
</div>
```

css

```
.one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -1px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    -1px -1px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         -1px -1px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
```

jquery

```
$("div").setInterval(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass(".two");
}, 1000);
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KXp4D/2/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`setInterval()` is not a *jQuery* function, but a simple *JavaScript* one.

To use it, you need to change your code to

```
setInterval(function() {
   $("div").toggleClass("two");
}, 1000);
```

This will work, but like an on-off; to make it smooth, you can use CSS3 transition like this:

```
transition: all 1s ease;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QCSYd/1/)

Note that you won't need necessary javascript, this can be done in pure CSS3.

Comment: This isn't my question, but I think this is the best and easiest way.

Comment: Ahahahah didn't noticed you weren't OP (but you can upvote too ;)

Comment: On more question... How do I do  "transition: all 1s ease;" in jquery

Comment: Ho do you add that CSS3 property with jquery instead that with CSS ? I don't know why you should do that - it would be better to have it on CSS and toggling the class with jQuery, but: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10237742/1654265

Answer (score 9):

Pure CSS Example [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KXp4D/10/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes shadow {
    0% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
    50% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
    100% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
}
@-moz-keyframes shadow {
    0% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
    50% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
    100% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
}
@keyframes shadow {
    0% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
    50% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 13px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
    100% {box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);}
}

.one {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red;
    box-shadow: -1px -1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}
.one:hover {
    -webkit-animation: shadow 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: shadow 1s ease-in-out infinite;
    animation: shadow 1s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function() {
   var cl = $("div").hasClass('one') ? 'two' : 'one';
   $("div").attr('class', cl);
}, 1000);
```

You cannot add setInterval to an object. Use it like

```
setInterval(function(){
  // do stuff
}, 1000);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KXp4D/6/)

NOTE: For that smooth transition I added CSS transition on box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

In the Fiddle your `setInterval` method is not running correctly and the `toggle` doesn't have the correct args.  Try this instead:

```
setInterval(function() {
   $("div").toggleClass("one");
   $("div").toggleClass("two");
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/LKXLc/

```
setInterval(function() {
if( $("div").hasClass("one"))
{
      $("div").removeClass("one").addClass("two");
}
else
{
      $("div").removeClass("two").addClass("one");
}
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS

[Demo](https://www.geekinsta.com/creating-a-pulse-effect-using-css/)

**HTML Markup**

```
<a href="#" id="msElem">Click Here</a>
```

**CSS**

```
@keyframes msPulseEffect {
   0% {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   }
 100% {
     box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   }
 }
 #msElem{
   margin: 30px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   color:white;
   background-color: #0078D7;
   border-radius: 50%;
   text-decoration: none;
   animation: msPulseEffect 1s infinite;
 }
```