# JQuery set CSS Transform, Translate Properties in Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-animations

I cannot seem to set the CSS properties of transform using Jquery.

> Here is my Code: https://jsfiddle.net/op7Lsvdp/

These are the two methods I have unsuccessfully tried.

```
$('.slideToCart').css({
  '-webkit-transform' : 'translate(left, top)',
  '-moz-transform'    : 'translate(left, top)',
  '-ms-transform'     : 'translate(left, top)',
  '-o-transform'      : 'translate(left, top)',
  'transform'         : 'translate(left, top)'
});

$('.slideToCart').css('transform', 'translate(50px, 50px)');
$('.slideToCart').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(50px, 50px)');
```

Thank You,

Comment: look at this method of sorting vendors prefixes (STEP3) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10237742/6213434

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think important thing about **css** method is that it is not changing your **class** property, but it is changing **style** property of object that you are calling it on.

This will do:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.buttonHolder').click(function(){
        $(this).find("span").toggleClass('fadeText');
        var button = $(this).find("button");
        button.toggleClass('shrink');

        var position = $('.target').position();
        var left = position.left + 'px';
        var top = position.top + 'px';

        var buttonHolder = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            buttonHolder.css({'transform' : 'translate(' + left +', ' + top + ')'});
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I still cant seem to get it work even with preset numbers instead of my variables any idea why that might be?

Comment: Did you try buttonHolder solution?

Comment: since v1.8 jquery takes care of prefixes, so you only need to use the regular transform. See about halfway http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Yes, we can skip top lines if you are using > v1.8 jquery

Comment: Thanks for all the help I still cant seem to get it to work I'll fiddle with it some more and see if I can get it

Comment: I see so I was thinking I was actually manipulating the class when in reality I was just changing the style. A key concept I cant believe I didn't understand. Up-voted and checked.

Comment: well thanks so much @ErikMcFarland for giving credit or at least reply to my answer which reveiled the actual problem... which was not targeting your elements correctly

Comment: @yezzz I don't have enough credit to up vote yet sadly I did up-vote yours it just wont take effect until I have enough credit.

Comment: well, I think my answer gave away what was wrong, so I had expected my answer to be accepted... and not Gevorg use my suggestion in his code. So I got a little pissed. Those generally last about 10 seconds... so no worries. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 3):

You're adding styles to `.slideToCart` elements, but there are none! See the console log:

https://jsfiddle.net/op7Lsvdp/2/

You're adding those classes after click on `.buttonHolder`, so maybe that's the time you want to add the `.css`